# Swift (iOS8) SpriteKit waiting for an animation to complete inside a running loop before moving onto the next?

Tags: swift, ios8

**When inside a loop in swift, how can I ensure that an animation completes first before the next iteration and therefore new animation call occurs?**

Apologies that I may be covering old ground here with a question similar to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285374/ios7-spritekit-how-to-wait-for-an-animation-to-complete-before-resuming-method-e) that used Objective-C, rather than swift. I just wanted to make my own query as I've pretty much started off in Swift and have not found a lot of clear help on this issue.

Below is some simple code to help demonstrate my question. The function `moveAlong` simply takes an array of CGPoints which I've hard coded as below:

```
let point1 = CGPointMake(100, 100)
let point2 = CGPointMake(100, 400)
let point3 = CGPointMake(400, 400)
array.append(point1)
array.append(point2)
array.append(point3)
moveAlong(array) //calls the function passing in our points


func moveAlong(thesePoints:[CGPoint]) {

var length = thesePoints.count  //capture the length of array

//for every point in the array
for i in 0..<length { 

    //plug point from the array into our move action here
    let move = SKAction.moveTo(thesePoints[i], duration: 1)
    let spinAction = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(2*M_PI), duration:1)


    //both above actions are sequenced together
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([move,spinAction])

    //run the sequence on sprite
    sprite.runAction(sequence)

    }
}
```

The current behaviour of this code is a kind of weird looking hybrid of all three actions moving the sprite to the final position at `point3` followed by all 3 of the spin actions (Not too sure how sprite kit is dealing with what appears to be 3 animation calls on the same sprite, at the same time?). Not quite the behaviour I'm after..

What I'm looking for is a way to make the each animation call execute in entirety before moving onto the next. So, hopefully this will make the sprite move to each point, perform a spin and then continue onto the next animation. Obviously the important part with this example is that must happen within a loop.

I clearly have a lot to learn here so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Matt

Answer (score 0):

Hint : instead of running your `sequence` action directly, store it in an array. After the `for` loop ended, your array should contains 3 actions in that case. You can now create another sequence action to run these 3 actions.

Comment: Ok thanks I understand what your saying here which does fix this small case, as you mentioned. But what would your answer be if the loop had to apply these actions to a different sprite through each iteration? So, rather than applying the actions to a single sprite we would be accessing a new one each time using something like `spritesArray[i].runAction(sequence)`.